# aspnet session lost every postback, just in firefox

Tags: asp.net, session

So long story short, in Chrome or IE I can hit refresh on my web app to my hearts content and the session remains. In Firefox I lose my session every postback (the Session_End method is called in Global.asax).

Any suggestions? This obviously sounds like a browser configuration issue...but I can't see anything that would cause this behavior.

Update:

So it turns out it was my code which handles the browser being closed. For some reason in Firefox the window.onunload event is getting fired every post back (which called a method which ended the session). Now I have to figure out why Firefox is behaving like that. Everyday I like firefox less!

Update 2:
Turns out using onunload is behaving as documented in firefox, but Chrome is just smarter with it or something, still investigating, but i'll mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

I'd make sure that you don't have [cookies disabled](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-and-disable-cookies-website-preferences) in Firefox. According to MSDN's [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> By default, SessionID values are stored in a cookie.

Comment: Yeah, cookies are enabled in Firefox. I've tried changing my site to go cookieless and store the sessionid in the url, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: The session ends even with cookieless tracking? :/ Are you using in-process or sql session-state management?

Comment: ok, found out why the session is ending, i'll update my original question.